# Where can the Group Transient Key be found by a client after the WPA2 4-Way Handshake?

Tags: wpa2, key

I am undertaking a project that looks into the ‘Hole 196’ exploit found in WPA2. I am attempting to uncover the current Group Transient Key that my AP is using in an attempt to use it myself to encrypt packets. I am connecting to the AP using Kali Linux VM with a USB wireless adapter but have no idea how the key could be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what about a little research?

Here's your primary ressource: [802.11i-2004](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11i-2004.pdf). If you can't find the Group Transient Key in that document, it's because that is commonly called Group *Temporal* Key.

The answer to your slightly imprecise question "Where is the GTK located?" is basically, inside the Supplicants, after getting it from the Authenticator.

These roles are described in the standards document linked above.

The hierarchy of who generates what key from which secret is probably most concisely defined in 8.5.1.3.

## EDIT

With your edit:

> I am connecting to the AP using Kali Linux VM with a USB wireless adapter but have no idea how the key could be accessed.

Ask your WPA supplicant.

Depending on how *you* set up things this is, most likely, kept by `wpa_supplicant`. You can run `wpa_supplicant` with the `-dd -K` to enable **a lot** of debug output, and to include `K`eys in that.

Note that "how do I use `wpa_supplicant`" is not really on-topic here.

Comment: I am aware the GTK is stored by the supplicant but I am unsure how to access the key as a supplicant running Kali Linux. I have updated my question so it is more clear.

Comment: -.- you know, you could save people a lot of work by actually asking your question in the first place...